# Is there a way to change the spec file location when generating a component with Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I like using the CLI to generate a new component (or any other schematic): `ng generate component path/to/my/component`. I also like that a spec skeleton is generated. But I don't want it to be beside the component's source. I would like to place the spec files in a dedicated test folder (as in most languages).

I know I can do it manually, but is there a way to configure the CLI (or any other solution) to change its behavior when generating a schematic? There is an option to disable spec generation, but nothing else to my knowledge.

Now, why do I want to do that? In an Angular project it's really quick to have many files. And this has an impact on productivity. When you work on sources you don't care on spec files (some will argue that you are supposed to work on both at the same time). So basically I want to minimize the scrolls in the editor (by reducing the number of files when it's not needed or place them in context).

Comment: I would guess there's nothing built in to do this, because it brings up too many other questions (what directory? In or out of src/? Does it need additional TS or testing config?) and the Angular style guide says keep those files together. You'd have to write your own schematic.

Comment: Ok, interesting (I did not know it was possible to write your own schematics). In my dreams there is already someone who did a fork on the existing schematics since I am not the first one to encounter this (I saw an issue on Github dating back 2015 or 2016). But actually I think that the "many questions" you are talking about @jonrsharpe could be fixed with one, max. two angular.json configuration options (e.g. useTestDir (boolean) and/or specDir). The rest is Karma/jasmine config that can go in their respective config files I think